# While Loop with 2 variables in Python

Tags: python, while-loop

What is the value of `y` after the following statements?

```
 x = 100
 y = 0
 while x > 50:
     y = y + 1
     x = x - 1
```

I'm having trouble with questions that involve 2 variables.

Comment: loop runs for `50` times, so `y` incremented `50` times by `1`. Then what should be the value?

Comment: I don't see that you are taking care of "indentation" which is a must in python.

Comment: Which part are you stuck on?

Comment: Unless you're taking a pencil-and-paper test, problems like this are best solved empirically: `print(y)`.

Answer (score 3):

Step through the first few iterations of the loop, look for a pattern, and extrapolate.

```
x = 100          # x = 100
y = 0            # x = 100 y = 0
if x > 50:       # x = 100 y = 0
    y = y + 1    # x = 100 y = 1
    x = x - 1    # x = 99  y = 1
if x > 50:       # x = 99  y = 1
    y = y + 1    # x = 99  y = 2
    x = x - 1    # x = 98  y = 2
if x > 50:       # x = 98  y = 2
    y = y + 1    # x = 98  y = 3
    x = x - 1    # x = 97  y = 3
if x > 50:       # x = 97  y = 3
    y = y + 1    # x = 97  y = 4
    x = x - 1    # x = 96  y = 4
if x > 50:       # x = 96  y = 4
    y = y + 1    # x = 96  y = 5
    x = x - 1    # x = 95  y = 5
if x > 50:       # x = 95  y = 5
    y = y + 1    # x = 95  y = 6
    x = x - 1    # x = 94  y = 6
...
if x > 50:       # x = 52  y = 48
    y = y + 1    # x = 52  y = 49
    x = x - 1    # x = 51  y = 49
if x > 50:       # x = 51  y = 49
    y = y + 1    # x = 51  y = 50
    x = x - 1    # x = 50  y = 50
if x > 50:       # x = 50  y = 50
(false, end process)
```

Comment: Waw! nothing can be better helpful than this answer.